# MySQL how do I insert now() date when doing a LOAD DATA INFILE?

Tags: mysql, date

**I'm importing data from a file 'infile.txt' and I'm using the table:** *People* (ID is auto_incremented) **to insert it into**

```
ID DATE NAME
```

**infile.txt**

```
Ben
Jim
Jack
```

**I'm using this method**

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/infile.txt'      
INTO TABLE People
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(DATE, NAME);
```

**Desired output**

```
   ID  DATE                 NAME
    1  2012-03-06 15:13:40  Ben
    2  2012-03-06 15:13:41  Jim
    3  2012-03-06 15:13:42  Jack
```

Comment: You could create `timestamp` field with `current_timestamp` default value

Comment: example for what exactly? The advice is pretty clear

Comment: Sorry I got it, I was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set your `DATE` field as a timestamp:

```
ALTER TABLE `People` CHANGE `DATE` `DATE` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

The `DATE` field will automatically contain the time that the record was inserted, so you just ignore that field in your load. Also `DATE` isn't a good choice for a field name, as it's a reserved word that should be enclosed in backticks.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to ignore the dates in the file, and use NOW() instead, then you can simply load the date from the file into a user variable and ignore it, then explicitly set the date to NOW(), like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '~/infile.txt'      
INTO TABLE People
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@DATE, NAME)
SET DATE = NOW();
```